# Ассемблер: нужна помощь в разборе кода

Tags: ассемблер

Задание: Ввести с клавиатуры строку и строку из двух чисел. Первое число указывает начало подстроки для ввода на экран, второе количество символов из первой строки, которое необходимо вывести на экран.
Мой первый вопрос: для чего нужна пятая строка *STDOUT* equ 1?\

```
.MODEL small ;отводим под стек и под данные по 64Кб код занимает 1 сегмент, данные и стек обьеденены в одну группу
.STACK 100h ;отмечаем начало сегмента стека
.DATA ;отмечаем начало сегмента данных
 
_STDOUT_ equ 1 ; из синтаксического описания видно, что с помощью equ идентификатору 
;можно ставить в соответствие как числовые выражения, так и текстовые строки, 
    ;а псевдооператор “=” может использоваться только с числовыми выражениями;
vivod db 0Dh, 0Ah, '$' ; $-кон. стр.
 
String db 82 dup(?); выделение памяти для строки 
PosLen db 14 dup(?); выделение памяти для строки (числа)
Pos dw ? ; память для первого числа
Len dw ? ; для второго
 
.CODE ;отмечаем начало сегмента кодов
preob proc ; процедура преобразования из строки в число
xor ax, ax
mov bx, ax
mov cx, 10 ; для реализации цикла
_repeat:
mov bl, [si] ; помещаем в bl символ строки
inc si ; в si переходим к ячейке следующего символа
sub bl, '0'; преобразуем ASCII код в число
jb _break ; если SF = 1 то выходим из процедуры(указывает, что между числами стоит пробел, числовой код пробела меньше числового кода нуля)
cmp bl, 9 ; сравниваем, если число больше 9 - то это символ - идём на выход
ja _break
mul cx
add ax, bx ;прибавляет в регистр ax нужное число
jmp _repeat
_break:
ret ; возврат в в главный код
preob endp
 
main PROC
;инициализация сегментного регистра ds адресом сегмента данных
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
 
;ввод строки
mov [String], byte ptr 80
mov ah, 0Ah
lea dx, [String]
int 21h
 
;ввод строки чисел
mov al,10 ; перенос строки
int 29h ; быстрый вывод символов на экр(экон байт)
mov [PosLen], byte ptr 14
mov ah, 0Ah
 
lea dx, [PosLen]
int 21h
 
;преобразование строки в первое число
lea si, [PosLen+2]
call preob
mov [Pos], ax
call preob
mov [Len], ax
 
mov al,10 ; перенос строки
int 29h ; быстрый вывод символов на экр(экон байт)
mov ah, 40h ;номер функции помещается в ah
mov bx, _STDOUT_ ;в bx хранится дескриптор стандартного выходного потока
mov cx, [Len] ; кол-во выводимых символов
lea dx, [String+1] ; адрес буфера вывода
add dx, [Pos] ; берем 1 сим. и добавляем число, чтобы перейти к нужному нам символу
int 21h 
 
;завершение программы
xor ax,ax
int 16h
mov ax,4c00h
int 21h
MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: _STDOUT_ использeтся вот в этой `mov bx, _STDOUT_ ;в bx хранится дескриптор стандартного выходного потока` строке

Comment: а что такое дескриптор стандартного выходного потока??

Comment: [man 2 read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) (и SEE ALSO тоже читайте)